# How to reload/replace external javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery game (simple card memory game) that I got from github.

It does not have a "new game" button so once the game is finished, there is no way to restart the game without refreshing the page.

I do not want to refresh the whole page so I tried creating a click event like this.

```
<li style="color:black; font-weight:600"><a href="#">new game</a></li>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
            $("body").load("game.js");
            });

});
```

On click, the external .js is not being replaced.

I've googled but haven't found anything.

Maybe this is not possible?  I've read that once the .js is loaded, there is no way to delete that .js with .click.

Is that true?

If the loaded .js cannot be replaced, how can I build the "new game" function?

Thanks for answering this simple, yet puzzling (puzzling to a newb like me.) question for me.

Comment: Couldn't you add your own code that resets a bunch of things? I'm guessing that's not ideal, and really is irrelevant of the question you're asking. I guess you could always do: `.load("game.js?_=" + new Date().getTime());` because the browser might be caching the contents of game.js

Comment: Maybe caching has nothing to do wit it, I don't think.  I am trying to create a button so that during the game, if the person wants to re-start, the game will be loaded fresh.  

Maybe there isn't a simple solution to this.  Although it's hard to believe there isn't one.  

Basically, I am trying not to use ".reload" which refreshes the whole page.  Didn't think refreshing just the .js would be so difficult challenge but maybe it is?

Comment: can you post a live link, or at least a link to the github game..

Comment: @newbie_coder Maybe you're right about caching, but that's why I asked/suggested it in a comment. Did you try using the extra GET parameter I suggested to see if it has to do with caching at all? And I understand you don't want to reload the whole page, I didn't refer to that.

Answer (score 1):

There will be bad side effects, variables still set to their old values, etc. Reloading the script isn't the same as refreshing the page.

For example if you have a variable `currentScore` which starts out at 0 and then raises as you play, reloading the script won't necessarily reset that to 0, it will likely still be at 51245 or whatever the last score was, basically messing everything up. This will apply to myriads of other things as well. Intervals that were going will now be doubled up. Events will be added again and the old ones not unset, double calling everything. The list goes on and on.

Basically this game seems to have poor architecture and needs work in order to properly reset. When something has a fundamental flaw in it's logic and architecture it's often not as simple as a quick fix to make it work. Features like restarting the game often have to be planned as part of the coding from the first lines of code typed.

Comment: Downvote it all you want, it doesn't change the fact that it's the truth, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Look at `jQuery.getScript()` -  [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) url

Comment: My question isn't how to ajax in external js.  My question is how to delete/remove/replace already loaded .js on click.

Comment: not so easy to unload JS :) js normally attaches event handlers, initalizes variables and so on ... you can remove the JS but the handlers already initialized will stay. If it is a class and have destroy method, you can invoke it ... afther taht reload the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fetch and run the script again I'm guessing you may have some weird lingering side effects from global variables or junk left in the DOM. It would probably be best to let the script clean up after itself, is there some kind of reset function within game.js that you can call?

---

If there's no reset then running the javascript file again may do the trick:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'game.js';
$(document.head).append( script );
```

If the game is well behaved and only manipulates things within its canvas, you may want to try removing the canvas from the dom and recreating it before importing the script: `$('#gameWrapper').remove(); $(document.body).append('<div id="gameWrapper"></div>')`. This will help clear out some of the residual event handlers and DOM junk.

Comment: No.  It's a very simple game. No such reset function.  I am just trying to learn jQuery with it.

Comment: I think if they're going to "reload" the script, they'd need to remove the previous script first. I just tested something like what you have (which is what I thought could do what the OP wants) but variables are acting weird. If I declare a variable `a` in the external file with a value of `0`, then set it in my HTML file to like `23`, use your code (including removing the original script block), and alert `a` again, it's still `23`. If I alert `a` in the external file, it says `0`.

Comment: ianpgall: I just tested and I think this is due to the browser asynchronously fetching the script. If you do `head.append(script)` and then immediately `alert(a)`, the browser has not had a chance to fetch and execute the script. Try using `setTimeout(function(){ alert(a); }, 1000);` to give the browser a second to fetch and execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove js file using this jQuery.

```
$j('script[src=game.js]').remove();
```

I try this in page load only.